# How to capture the build number from the Buildbot

Tags: python, buildbot

Is there a variable that I can access in `master.cfg`? The docs aren't clear at all. Thanks.

Comment: Has my answer been helpful to you, or is it still lacking something?  I'm happy to improve it if it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

There are ways of getting this information, but it depends on where you are trying to access it.

If you are inside a `doStepIf` procedure (as a parameter to `addStep`), this should work:

```
def insideDoStepIf(step):
    step.build.getStatus().number
```

If you are trying to prioritize your builders by their next build number, this should work:

```
def buildPriority(buildmaster, builders):
    builders.sort(key=lambda b: b.builder_status.nextBuildNumber)
    return builders

c['prioritizeBuilders'] = buildPriority
```

If you are interested in getting this information in a `messageFormatter` function for a `buildbot.status.mail.MailNotifier`, try this:

```
def formatEmail(mode, name, build, results, master_status):
    for builder in master_status.getBuilderNames():
        master_status.getBuilder(builder).nextBuildNumber
```

I did not *test* these, and I can't guarantee that the api here is stable, but I'm pretty confident that these should work, as I'm doing a few similar things (though, not with build number) in my own master.cfg

Comment: Heyy Nate ! I'm executing a shell script to start a build and I need to capture build number of a failed build from buildbot and I have multiple builder in master. please tell me how can I do that ? I did not find this "doStepIf" method you mentioned in the answer.